# Find Lower than

Tags: javascript

Any idea what's wrong here?
I have to count how many consecutive numbers are lower than `_number`.

```
const data = [1,1,2,3,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,6,7,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1];
function getBelow(_number) {
  let counter = 0;
  let max = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    if(data[i] < _number){
      counter++;
    } 
    if(data[i] > _number && counter > max){
      max = counter;
      counter = 0;
    } 
  }
  console.log(max);
}

getBelow(1.1);
```

It should console.log the last 20 zero but shows 7.

Comment: Because you never set `max`, when the loop ends, and the current `counter` is bigger.

Comment: At the end: `max = Math.max(max, counter);`

Comment: Btw `data[i] > _number` should probably be `>=`, and you only reset, when `counter > max`, which will cause problems.

Comment: question:  One check is for number < value.  The other is number > value.  What happens if they are the same?  You are ignoring those.

Comment: Anyway all you have to do is remove 'data[i] > _number && ' as that check is unnecessary and is causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the redundant condition `data > _number` and at the end, you need to get the maximum of `max` and `count`.

```js
const data = [1,1,2,3,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,6,7,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1];
function getBelow(_number) {
  let counter = 0;
  let max = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i] < _number) {
      counter++;
    } else if (counter > max) {
      max = counter;
      counter = 0;
    }
  }
  max = Math.max(max, counter);
  console.log(max);
}

getBelow(1.1);
```